# Firestore document RBAC- FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to restrict access to a `collection` based on a users "role" on the document as well as whether they're signed in.

Just checking if they are signed in works:

```
rules_version = '2';

function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /workspaces/{workspace} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn();
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to make it a bit more granular, [I'm following this Google guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access). When I configure it exactly the same my frontend client errors with `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`. However, testing the rule in the Firebase portal works(?).

```
rules_version = '2';

function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}

function getRole(rsc) {
  return rsc.data.access[request.auth.uid];
}

function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
  return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array);
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /workspaces/{workspace} {
      allow read: if isOneOfRoles(resource, ["owner", "viewer"]);
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned, testing the rule via Firebase works, however when querying from my frontend app it fails.

```js
// VueJS
let workspace = []

async fetchWorkspaces() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    await db.collection('workspaces').get().then(response => {
        response.forEach(snapshot => {
            this.workspaces.push(snapshot.data());
        })
    })
}
```

Database document

[image]

I've also tried storing the RBAC for each user as a document in a subcollection and using the following rule

```
allow read: if isSignedIn() && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/workspaces/$(workspace)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
```

Still doesn't work. I can only seem to grant broad access (is signed in)

Comment: What is the value of `fb.workspacesCollection`?

Comment: Other remark: Note that in the documentation you refer to, the functions are within the `service cloud.firestore {match /databases/{database}/documents {...}}`. I've not tried your rules (neither analyzed them into detail) so maybe this remark is irrelevant but it may happen that functions need to be in the same block than the rule calling them (e.g. if you pass variables).

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, Sorry thats just an import of the standard firebase.collection('workspaces') let me update for clarity

Comment: @RenaudTarnec interesting, okay I'll try shifting the functions. The `isSignedIn()` function works as is but maybe the others are failing because of that. However, when testing the rules in the portal it works fine. Its only when I try and query from JS that I get permission issues.